# Failed to create push channel: 13006 Extended code: 0x800705b4

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, microsoft-edge, chromium, flutter-web

I'm having an issue with Flutter FCM web push notifications. Everything works perfectly fine in Chrome, but in Edge I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: AbortError: Registration failed - push service error
    

    at Object.createErrorWithStack (errors.dart:284:10)
    at Function._throw (core_patch.dart:288:28)
    at Function.throwWithStackTrace (errors.dart:108:5)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (zone.dart:1413:11)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
    at async_patch.dart:166:15
```

The issue appears to be intermittent. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Killing Edge tasks/rebooting doesn't seem to help, but resetting network adapter - does help. The `edge://push-internals` shows following error:

```
Subscribe failed
Occurred: 3/29/2022, 12:50:38 PM PDT
Status: Failed to create push channel: 13006 Extended code: 0x800705b4
Server key: BDOU99+h67HcA6J...2xGpWwzjfAnG4=
Type: Service worker
origin: http://localhost:50000/
service-worker-registration-id: 2
```

The application is setup as described in
[Flutter Fire Web setup](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web/) and [Usage](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage).

Google search on `Failed to create push channel: 13006 Extended code: 0x800705b4` returns no results, but is the key here. Anybody knows what that means?

Non-debug Edge browser log:

```
Connection status
Type: WinRT WNS client
Server: https://client.wns.windows.com/
State: Disconnected
Disconnected: 3/29/2022, 12:56:34 PM PDT
Disconnect reason: Connection error: 13018
Connection attempts: 0
```

Comment: Based on your description, the issue is intermittent and your network connection appears to be unstable. This may be the cause of the problem, you can also try to test this issue on another stable network connection. If I've misunderstood something, could you provide a minimal code example that reproduces this problem, it would help to solve the problem.

Comment: We have concluded that this is a Win10/Edge bug. Waiting for MS to clarify to post the official answer for this. Thanks, @XudongPeng